# what tampers binbary file that ends with RPM verify failed with md5. size and time

Tags: python, php, linux, rpm, yum

I have package (for example: php70) which works fine, after installation or upgrade rpm --verify outputs success.

Suddenly something modifies it somehow and rpm --verify fails, showing md5, size and time has been changed.

Now i want to analyze and find what makes it to change how this package is modified, which process did it?

As this package is not custom i can't modify it's content for debugging.

Do you have any ideas how to debug, investigate such problems?

Comment: So, did you do a `stat php70.rpm` yet?  When was it last modified?  Is this a busy machine?  If it was a user, and limited number of users access the machine, does `last | head` narrow down?  If a system process may have messed with it... check cron?

Comment: @MarkStewart Thanks for comment.

yes i did, it shows time when it was modified.
Machine is created in ci stage , run tests and then destroys. 
In tests there are not any code that can harm binay files, (edit, delete, modify).
I need to know how to investigate in this cases.